# Averaging of unit vectors in spacetime with Minkowski signature

Tags: geometry, vector-fields, general-relativity

Averaging of unit vectors in Euclidean space over $S_1$ is a well-known result. If we consider unit vector $\vec{n}=(\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi))$ such as $\vec{n}^2=1$, then the following average:
\begin{align}
\langle n_i n_j \rangle=\frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij},
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\langle f(\phi) \rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi f(\phi).
\end{align}
But what about two dimensional Minkowski spacetime? Then unit vector coorsponds to $n_t^2-n_x^2=1$. It is natural to expect, that:
\begin{align}
\langle n_\mu n_\nu \rangle=\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu},
\end{align}
but how to show this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to average $$\cosh^2\phi=\frac{\cosh2\phi+1}{2},$$ $$\sinh^2\phi=\frac{\cosh2\phi-1}{2},$$ $$\cosh\phi\sinh\phi=\frac{\sinh2\phi}{2}$$ over the unit hyperbola. The relevant integrals diverge to infinity, though you could try something like the Cauchy principal value: $$\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{\int_{-a}^af(\phi)\,d\phi}{\int_{-a}^a\,d\phi}$$